# computing an indeterminate form of a limit

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

I need a hint on computing this one limit:

$$\lim_{n \to\infty}\,\frac{2\cdot4^n+3\cdot n^4}{4\cdot n^6-3\cdot 3^n +3n}$$

Thank you

Comment: $$n^4 <4^n\\n^6 <3^n $$

Comment: use lhospital rule multiple time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by $4^n$ both the numerator and denominator.